# Gatsby-Source-Wordpress configuration

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

Gatsby-Source-WordPress
Gatsby Develop 
 returns:
"The server response was "404 Not Found"

Running Gatsby default Starter
Fresh install of wordpress all on localhost.

wordpress is here: localhost/freshinstall
I see json data here: localhost/freshinstall/wp-json/
Permalinks in wordpress set to: Post Name

gatsby-source-wordpress is the only plugin installed in gatsby:

```
   {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        // your wordpress source
        baseUrl: `localhost/freshinstall`,
        protocol: `http`,
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        useACF: true
      }
    },
```

Expecting to be able to access information in wordPress.

The following is what I see:

```
my-default-starter dk$ gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.067 s
success load plugins - 42.771 s
success onPreInit - 0.034 s
success initialize cache - 0.061 s
success copy gatsby files - 2.423 s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.052 s

Path: /freshinstall/wp-json
The server response was "404 Not Found"

 ERROR 

Plugin gatsby-source-wordpress returned an error Cannot read property 'data' of undefined



  TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

  - fetch.js:134 fetch
    [my-default-starter]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/fetch.js:134:21

  - next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7


warn The gatsby-source-wordpress plugin has generated no Gatsby nodes. Do you need it?
success source and transform nodes - 1.840 s
success building schema - 1.270 s
success createPages - 0.007 s
success createPagesStatefully - 1.266 s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.089 s
success update schema - 0.078 s
success extract queries from components - 25.299 s
success write out requires - 0.165 s
success write out redirect data - 0.044 s
success Build manifest and related icons - 0.402 s
success onPostBootstrap - 0.458 s
⠀
info bootstrap finished - 269.881 s
⠀
success Generating image thumbnails — 6/6 - 2.762 s
success run static queries - 3.311 s — 3/3 0.91 queries/second
success run page queries - 0.077 s — 5/5 93.18 queries/second
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 105741ms                                                                                                  3:25:50 PM
⠀
You can now view gatsby-starter-default in the browser.
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/
⠀
View GraphiQL, an in-browser IDE, to explore your site's data and schema
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/___graphql
⠀
Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build
⠀
ℹ ｢wdm｣:
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9196

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my own machine was messed up.

It took forever to resolve, what ultimately solved the issue was changing how apache was setup on the machine. The link localhost/domain wasn't literally what it was. I broke apache, broke mysql, then fixed both then had to change a port and finally it works like this now:

localhost:8888/domain

Everything in Gatsby-Source-WordPress worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this same problem and here are the things I did:

- My MAMP settings had the default port as 80. Local Wordpress could be accessed through http://localhost. I reverted MAMP ports to default, so the local url became http://localhost:8888/*your domain name if applied*
- I forced stop sqld which was running concurrently on my Mac.
- I went to phpMyAdmin and disabled all the active plugins.
- I went to wp-admin and reset permalinks to *post name*. That had already been set as *post name*, but still click the *Save* button anyway to commit the change.

Looking back, I have no idea what was the culprit, but hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your config should look like this but if not let me know and i'll fix :).

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        baseUrl: process.env.API_URL,

        protocol: process.env.API_PROTOCOL,

        hostingWPCOM: false,

        useACF: true,

        includedRoutes: [
          "**/categories",
          "**/posts",
          "**/pages",
          "**/media",
          "**/tags",
          "**/taxonomies",
          "**/users",
          "**/menus",
          "**/portfolio",
          "**/services",
          "**/qualifications",
          "**/gallery",
          "**/logo",
          "**/location",
        ],
      },
    },
}
```